How can you change a continuous variable into a categorical variable?
I am trying to do a regression analysis, but I don't get any results when I include an interaction term. I think what goes wrong is that in the interaction, I either have a value of 0 or 4, but I guess SPSS “thinks” it is a continuous variable and doesn’t have enough data points in between 0 and 4 to fit the regression line.
**How can I change the interaction term into a categorical variable? **
The interaction term consists of combining "conditie1_welgeencor" and "conditie2_newsformat".
I tried centering my variables, standardizing my variables, categorizing by giving values to my variables.

If the problem is that SPSS is using a categorical variable as a continuous one, you can change the measurement level of the variable before the analysis like this:
Variable Level YourVarName (Nominal).

